# How to split 1 column value into 2 with new column name

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example :

```
A     |B    |C  |D  |E  |F        
LOH_ANKH  | 123 |345    |567    |544    |654
```

Output should be like

```
A   |Reg       |B       |C      |D      |E      |F        
LOH |ANKH      | 123    |345    |567    |544    |654
```

Comment: A bit of context would surely help

Comment: `df[['A', 'Reg']] = df.A.str.split('_', expand = True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your row data is being fetched in the form of a list, and for the sake of providing you with an answer to split the first column, here's a short code to help you with splitting of strings. Adding the new column to wherever you want to is something that this solution does not address since it is not clear in the question as to where the new column is to be added.

```
row_data = ['LOH_ANKH', 123, 345, 567, 544, 654]
new_data = row_data[0].split('_')
col1 = new_data[0]
col2 = new_data[1]
print("Column1 : ",col1)
print("Column2 : ",col2)
```

**OUPUT:**

```
Column1 :  LOH
Column2 :  ANKH
```

Comment: @Karthike Upvote and Accept the answer if you think it helped.